# How can I delete a Development Package (not an Installed Package) programatically?

Tags: package, migration-tool, ant, package.xml, destructivechanges.xml

Under Setup > Create > Packages, I have deployed "packages" with prefix `033`

Under Setup > App Setup > Installed Packages, I have installed "packages" also with prefix `033`

I understand that it is possible to retrieve *Installed* Packages using the ant `sf:retrieve` tool:

```
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>InstalledPackage</name>
</types>
```

But I'm looking for *Development* Packages (like those created with `sf:deploy`) so I can destroy them.

[image: package-menu]

Is there a way to delete these guys (eg `destructiveChanges.xml`) without using the UI?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm pretty familiar with the [Metadata API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/) and deletion of Package 'definitions' is not supported presently it appears. The only thing i can think is accessing the Delete action via the page URL's, which is not ideal of course since its not supported.

I did also try this in destructiveChanges.xml, it did not work sadly. I should clarify, it did not error, which gave me some hope, but in the end the unmanaged package Test remained.

```
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <fullName>Test</fullName>
    <version>28.0</version>
</Package>
```

And this...

```
<target name="undeploypackage">
    <sf:deploy
        username="${sf.username}"
        password="${sf.password}"
        singlepackage="true"
        deployroot="${basedir}/undeploypackage"/>
</target>
```

Comment: brownie points awarded for trying... cheers